# Cannot find module '@angular-builders/custom-webpack/package.json'

Tags: single-spa-angular

I'm following the document on single-spa for angular. My angular version is 11+. I followed the steps from
https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-angular/#angular-cli through https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-angular/#finish-installation successfully.
But as subsequent step when I complete https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-angular/#configure-routes
and run the script at https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-angular/#serving at npm run serve:single-spa (npm run serve:single-spa:my-app) actually,
I get the following error:
[image: Cannot find module @angular-builders/custom-webpack/..]
Can anyone point out why this may be occuring and what's the remedy for this ?
This is the relevant log file
[image]

Answer (score 14):

You probably just forgot to run `npm install` before running your application. This was the problem in my case.

Another solution you can try is to delete `package-lock.json` then npm install again if you already have the node modules installed.

Answer (score 10):

Did you try:
"npm i -D @angular-builders/custom-webpack" in your SPA directory?

reference:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack

(Worked for me).

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the package.json file.
2. add "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^12.0.0"
3. to find the latest version of @angular-builders/custom-webpack go this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack?activeTab=versions
   and pick the latest version.
4. then npm install again

Answer (score 0):

For me it was "builderS" (what it should be) vs "builder" (what I had) which I incorrectly typed into my `angular.json`